# iOS: Make Status Bar Keep its Height When Hidden on non-iphoneX

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

When I hide my status bar with:

`UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true`

My other views shift up because the status bar disappears. This is weird because normally when you set a view to hidden it does not lose its height. This doesn't happen on iPhoneX however.

What can I do to hide the status bar without losing height? Is it possible to just make the status bar text transparent?

That would also solve my problem.

EDIT: People are wondering why I would do this. Well Snapchat does this. When you open a photo from stories the status bar disappears of the parent view but the height of where the status bar was stays the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your views are ultimately pinned to the top layout guide / safe area. It moves up when the status bar hides, so they move up too. If that's not what you want, don't do that.

(However, be careful, because your app needs to run on a bezel-free device such as the iPhone X.)

Here, for example, the button is pinned to the top of the main view, not the safe area. As you can see, it doesn't move when the status bar shows and hides (iPhone X and iPhone 5s are shown):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: By the way, the line `UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true` is a Bad Smell. That is _not_ the correct way to manage the visibility of the status bar.

Comment: Also, I found that on iPhoneX, hiding the status bar does not move views pinned to the safe area up. All other phones it does move.

Comment: @Micro You should override the property: `override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }`

Comment: So how do I do that? Your answer is pointless and doesn't tell me anything I don't already know.

Comment: Added screen shots showing that you can hold the subview steady by not pinning to the safe area.

Comment: Is the top constraint of the button to the superview the same value for your screenshots in iPhoneX and 5s?

Comment: No. That’s what the sentence “be careful, because your app needs to run on a bezel-free device such as the iPhone X” means in my answer.

Comment: @matt so this solution doesn't work then because it won't work on all devices.

Comment: I don’t see why not. The constraints were not hand tweaked; it all happened automatically thru code. The same app was shown in all the screenshots.